# Logic gates not working as expected

Tags: digital-logic

I've put together a ESP8266 based board which I want to deep sleep until a PIR sensor senses someone nearby. I put together some logic gates which should allow me to control whether or not the PIR sensor is enabled or not. PIR sensor is a SR602 which goes HIGH for 2.5 seconds once it senses someone.

[image: Circuit diagram]

The idea is the ESP pin should stay high while the ESP8266 isn't in sleep which should mean that the output to RST is always HIGH, then I turn the ESP pin to LOW in sleep so the PIR sensor can start-up the ESP again when it goes HIGH.

I did a simulation and it worked as I expected but on the board it seems that the inverter isn't inverting (tested with a multi-meter 3.3v in comes out as 3.3v, GND in GND out). No matter what I do with the ESP pin the PIR constantly triggers a reset.

Can anyone see where I went wrong here?

Edit: close up of the inverter
[image: closeup]

Comment: Maybe a problem with 2A input being undefined.

Comment: Sure you installed the correct parts?

Comment: ..and haven't fried them yet

Comment: Possibly fried but i was pretty careful because they are tiny. defiantly the right parts. 
I assumed 2A didn't need to be defined as it was unused.

Comment: Also make sure your pin numbering is correct on your footprint.

Comment: Yup, those are definitely tiny. If output == input I suspect a solder bridge. Can you provide a magnified photo of the chip in place?

Comment: To check for solder bridges, measure resistance between pins using your multimeter (with the circuit powered off).

Comment: This logic (NAND with an inverted input) can be implemented with a single [SN74AUP1G97](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74AUP1G97).

Comment: added  a closeup. ill try and tie the unused pins to ground

Comment: Can confirm, grounding the unused pin has caused the inverter to work properly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CL. Add your comment as an answer, and perhaps a bit more elaborating...

Answer (score 1):

Connect the 2A pin to V<sub>CC</sub> or GND.
When you leave a CMOS input open, not only will you get a much higher power consumption, but the corresponding output might oscillate in an uncontrolled way, which can affect the other logic in the device.

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74aup2g14) of the inverter says:

> All unused inputs of the device must be held at V<sub>CC</sub> or GND to ensure proper device operation. Refer to the TI application report, *Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs*, literature number [SCBA004](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scba004).

Also see [[FAQ] How does a slow or floating input affect a CMOS device?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/737694)